# Postgres SELECT* FROM table WHERE column-varchar=="string-example"?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE lawyer (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  name_url VARCHAR check(translate(name_url, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-', '') = '') NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

I want to `SELECT * FROM lawyer where name_url = "john-doe"`

Comment: You could use `SELECT * FROM lawyer where name_url = 'john-doe'` Which is pretty much what you wrote, but with single quotes around your string literal.

Comment: So what is your question? Don't use double-quotes for string literals, use single-quotes as in `'john-doe'`. Also, using `varchar` without specifying column width is kind of bad practice.

Answer (score 38):

Character literals are put into single quotes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM lawyer 
where name_url = 'john-doe';
```

See the manual for details:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Answer (score 1):

Looking for exact match:

```
select column1, column2 from mytable where column2 like 'string';
```

Pattern Match can be achieved using:(returns stringxx, stringyyy..)

```
select column1, column2 from mytable where column2 like 'string%';
```

This will return any column2 that matches `string***`.

For using **OR** condition, to compare multiple strings below one can be used:

```
select column1, column2 from mytable where column2 ~* 'string1|string2';
```